# Shell script, curl with variable as part of url

Tags: bash, curl, jq

I am writing a small bash script that gets the profile of a Minecraft user from their username. However, when I run the following script, the `profile_json` variable comes out blank while the `uuid_json` and `uuid` variables have the content they should.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# settings
username="Notch"


# script
uuid_json=$(curl https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/$username)
echo $uuid_json
uuid=$(jq '.id' <<< "$uuid_json")
echo $uuid

profile_json=$(curl https://sessionserver.mojang.com/session/minecraft/profile/$uuid)
echo $profile_json
```

Moreover, the output from running the script in a terminal shows the `Current Speed` of `profile_json=$(curl https://sessionserver.mojang.com/session/minecraft/profile/$uuid)` as `0`. Any ideas as to why this would be?

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    56  100    56    0     0    160      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   160
{"name":"Notch","id":"069a79f444e94726a5befca90e38aaf5"}
"069a79f444e94726a5befca90e38aaf5"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS you can see by executing `echo $uuid` you got `"069a79f444e94726a5befca90e38aaf5"`
instead of `069a79f444e94726a5befca90e38aaf5` there should be no quotes.

`jq` has option to remove them it's `-r` with that everything works as expected(I think).

So change it to:

```
#!/bin/bash
# settings
username="Notch"

# script 
uuid_json=$(curl https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/$username)
echo $uuid_json
uuid=$(jq -r '.id' <<< "$uuid_json")                                                                                                                                                                           echo $uuid

profile_json=$(curl https://sessionserver.mojang.com/session/minecraft/profile/$uuid)
echo $profile_json
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `echo $uuid` outputs this:

```
"069a79f444e94726a5befca90e38aaf5"
```

But it really should be:

```
069a79f444e94726a5befca90e38aaf5
```

for the curl command to work. So, tweak your `jq` line to strip off quotation marks.